# Discord JS: I want to send an embed to the channel named "general" in every guild the bot is in and I'm getting an error

Tags: javascript, bots

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    console.log(guild.name);
    try {
    guild.channels.cache.find((x) => x.name == 'general').send(embed);
    } catch {
     //If message couldn't be sent
     console.log("Message wasn't sent for " + guild.name);
    }
   });
```

**Discord JS: I want to send an embed to the channel named "general" in every guild the bot is in and I'm getting an error. How can this be fixed, thanks in advance.**